# Preventing user from leaving input field

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer

I'm trying to do input field validation on the frontend (IE11).

The user is not supposed to leave the input field when the input validation fails. Nor should he be able to activate other controls on the page.

I try to regain the focus by using

```
element.onblur = (event) => { 
$(id).focus();
}
```

and block any clicks by using

```
window.onclick = (event) => {
event.preventDefault();
window.event.cancelBubble = true;
window.event.returnValue = false;
}
```

But there are still controls on the page (like Tabs and SelectBoxes) that get activated.

Any ideas on how to restrict the user to a certain input field?

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, please read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: one way would be to disable all the other fields and submit or other button except the field whose input validation has failed... hope it helps

Comment: Don't do this. It's awful UI design.

Comment: _“The user is not supposed to leave the input field when the input validation fails.”_ - that is really terrible UX. I might have lots of reasons to leave such a field - perhaps as simply as copy&pasting the value I want to fill in from elsewhere on the page.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `setInterval()` Method. Do this:

```js
var test = false;
var myTimer = setInterval( function() {
  if ( $( '.hello' ).val() == 'hello' ) {
    test = true;
    clearInterval( myTimer )
  } else {
    test = false;
    $( '.hello' ).focus()
  }
}, 1 )

window.onclick = function( e ) {
  if ( !test && !e.target.matches( '.hello' ) ) e.preventDefault()
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<p>
  <a href="https://stackoverflow.com">This is a Link</a>
  <input type="checkbox" id="chk">
  <label for="chk">This is a Checkbox</label>
</p>
<p>Only valid content is: <b>hello</b><br><input type="text" class="hello"></p>
```